# Nvidia-smi shows CUDA version, but CUDA is not installed

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, cuda

I am on Ubuntu 18.10. When I got my GPU (RTX 2070), I did "sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall". This installed the drivers. When I do "nvidia-smi" in terminal, I get this:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 415.25       Driver Version: 415.25       CUDA Version: 10.0     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce RTX 2070    Off  | 00000000:01:00.0  On |                  N/A |
|  0%   45C    P8     9W / 185W |    549MiB /  7949MiB |      6%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
```

, claiming that CUDA is installed. But when I do "nvcc -V", it can't find nvcc, so I don't think I installed CUDA correctly. To be safe that I don't run into issues later, how do I remove CUDA from nvidia-smi?

Comment: I believe it is the way the 415.25 driver reports.  I am running the same driver without CUDA installed and it shows the exact same thing.  It might be a bug in `nvidia-smi`.

Comment: Might want to see:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53422407/different-cuda-versions-shown-by-nvcc-and-nvidia-smi

Answer (score 13):

Be aware that the CUDA VERSION displayed by nvidia-smi associated with newer drivers is the DRIVER API COMPATIBILITY VERSION. It does not indicate anything at all about what CUDA version is actually installed. For example: A 410.72 driver will display CUDA VERSION 10.0 even when no CUDA toolkit is installed.

Answer (score 0):

If you think you have installed your cuda and nvcc -V won't show up it's probably missing a wrong link
any cuda version is  supposed to be seen  as /usr/local/cuda
and the binary compiler to be seen at /usr/local/cuda/bin/nvcc
otherwise you cannot compile the provided cuda's samples.

So just build
ln -s /your path to cuda-11 for ex/cuda-11  /usr/local/cuda
and check that /your_path_to_cuda-xx/bin/nvcc  exists !!!
After that set up your PATH to reflect /usr/local/cuda/bin

and your library to contain /your_path_cuda-xx/lib64 for the cuda runtime to be effective.

That's it
hoan