# Pytorch for very old GPU

Tags: nvidia, cuda, gpu

I've got Nvidia Quadro 2000 1GB from year 2010. From [Nvidia's CUDA legacy GPUs list](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-legacy-gpus) i can see it supports compute capability of 2.1.

I found a [CUDA compatibility manual](https://docs.nvidia.com/pdf/CUDA_Compatibility.pdf)  with a table of "CUDA Toolkit and Compatible Driver Versions" on page 4.

My driver version is 390.144 (from `nvidia-smi`), thus from the table CUDA 9.0 (9.0.76) should support the GPU.

Now I try to find an older version of Pytorch that supports CUDA 9.0. Fortunately, [Pytorch 1.1.0](https://pytorch.org/get-started/previous-versions/#v110)  supports CUDA 9.0.
Then I used this command to install this version of Pytorch `conda install pytorch==1.1.0 torchvision==0.3.0 cudatoolkit=9.0 -c pytorch`.

Unfortunately, `torch.cuda.is_available()` shows `False`. Am I doing something wrong?
Btw this is the output of `nvidia-smi` command.

```
(base) hell@Dell-Precision-T1600:~$ nvidia-smi
Sat Dec 25 03:39:47 2021       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 390.144                Driver Version: 390.144                   |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  Quadro 2000         Off  | 00000000:01:00.0  On |                  N/A |
| 33%   61C    P0    N/A /  N/A |    383MiB /   963MiB |     24%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0       938      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                            93MiB |
|    0      1249      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell                         159MiB |
|    0      3903      G   ...AAgAAAAAAAAACAAAAAAAAAA= --shared-files   125MiB |
|    0     17545      G   ...l/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_try/bin/python     1MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Look at section 3.1 Hardware Support, table 2 of your cuda compatibility link.  Your 2.1 compute capability (Fermi) doesn't even run driver 384.   Try dropping back to CUDA 8 and the 367-375 driver.

Comment: @ubfan1 I disagree. Plugging the OP's GPU into the [NVIDIA "Download Drivers" tool](https://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx?lang=en-us) suggests version 390.147. That would put the OP at CUDA 9.0, as they are just short of the requirement for 9.1

Comment: @ubfan1 I tried downgrading and broke the display driver. Had black screen on boot. Then used chroot environment to uninstall nivida drivers and update grub.

Comment: I confirm my last driver used on my Quadro 1000 was the 390 driver, so that should work with you quadro 2000.  Looks like Nvidia's older hardware web pages are not being maintained much, many dead links, like on our specific old Quadros.

Comment: Exactly, I don't know why CUDA 9.0 supported Pytorch is not recognizing my GPU.